# Use ajax in php for sending request to server

Tags: php, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I used ajax for sending request to server but it not get any response from php page.
    I am confused what is wrong in my code?

My Index.php page is:-

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        echo 'hello';
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

My html page is:-

```
    function showHint()
{

var xmlhttp;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("name").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","index.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
    </script>


</head>
<body>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
<input type="button" name="submit" value="Correct the Address" id="submit" onclick="showHint()"/>

</body>
</html>
```

What is wrong in my above code?please suggest me some solution?

Comment: Show what you return from index.php

Comment: Also you are returning from showHint before going to Ajax. Try removing it.

Comment: I suggest using jQuery for Ajax requests if possible.

Comment: i am just want to  return 'hello' from index.php and make it value of textbox by using innerhtml.

Answer (score 1):

You have syntax error `showHint()` so just check it

```
<input type="button" name="submit" value="Correct the Address" id="submit" onclick="showHint()"/></td>
```